# How to echo the date (numbers) from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I want to learn php & html so I'm making sketch websites. I want to know how to use echo statement.

I have this code

```
Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> !
Today's date is: <?php echo $_SESSION['trn_date']; ?>
```

But only $_Session[username] it's showing.  Trn_date shows blank.

This is my mysql's code.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `trn_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

);

EDIT

```
    require('db.php');
 // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
 if (isset($_POST['username'])){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $username = stripslashes($username);
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
 $email = stripslashes($email);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
 $password = stripslashes($password);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
 $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $query = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, trn_date) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$trn_date')";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

EDIT2: RESOLVED, BUT IT SHOWS ME THE SAME DATES.

```
 $antrenor = date("Y-m-d");
 $PrimulContract = date("Y-m-d");
 $ExpiraContract = date("Y-m-d");?>


 Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> ! 
Your subscribe will end in the date <?php echo $ExpiraContract; ?>
 You've subscribed at : <?php echo $PrimulContract; ?> 
On the date <?php echo $antrenor; ?> you will receive a new mail
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see all the keys and corresponding values

Comment: May be this is because you haven't create a session variable for date. If the date is in your database then first you have to fetch date from the database and then assign it's value to an variable and echo it.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to assign the values from the db to the session variables? And as Jajeep Paul says, try var_dump or print_r($_SESSION) to see what's actually in there. Also helpful if you can show us what's in the db. Are you sure the trn_date field actually has a value in it?

Comment: @Sunny and how I can do that? How I said, I want to learn, I know a few things only

Comment: @JohnMcMurray  done.

Comment: @JohnMcMurray, I said after fetching data from database assign it's value to any variable like $date = fetched_date; and echo it.

Comment: @AlxTioltisan Do you see the datetime in the database correctly? Also, post the code where you're fetching the record from the table.

Comment: Please avoid using mysql_query. You should be using mysqli. Mysql functions are known insecure

Comment: Right @DarrenH. Use mysqli functions.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul i'm not fetching. I followed an old tutorial about making register & login. I don't know how to fetch.  And yes, i see it ok on mysql

On php.net  it says I need to use this code.


 array mysql_fetch_row ( resource $result )

Comment: @AlxTioltisan According to your code just type **echo $trn_date;** to show date

Comment: @Sunny  it works now, but instead of date it shows "Array"

I need to fetch it, no?

Comment: @AlxTioltisan,  what it shows?

Comment: @Sunny http://i.imgur.com/AHoiAs5.png 

I've attached a photo.  

It shows "Array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Before echoing your date variable create

**Note:- You have to define this variable before echoing it.**

```
$date_today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

After creating this date variable now echo this variable when you are greeting.

```
Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> !
Today's date is: <?php echo $date_today; ?>
```

Fetch data from database

```
//fetch from database 
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection_name, "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username = '$usename' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

                $db_username = $row['username']; 
                $db_email = $row['email'];
                $db_expire = $row['expire_date'];
                $antrenor = $row['antrenor'];
                $primulContract = $row['primulContract'];
            }
    //Now you can echo these details if you want 

    // to show Expire Date you have to echo 
    echo $db_expire;
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: works fine, and I understand what should I do next time. Thanks

Comment: Works fine but there's a problem. It shows me the same date when I've added more data lines.  I've edited my post.

Comment: php date function always shows current date and time only. If you want to show date that was in your database you have to fetch it and show it

Comment: How can I fetch something?

Comment: did you insert your $antrenor,
 $PrimulContract, and
 $ExpiraContract in database?

Comment: yes. I have. I've changed the dates and it won't change. It shows the current date (today's)

Comment: Ok @AlxTioltisan, I have edited the code try it. And if you want to insert date in database don't insert php variable. You can just insert date and time with now() function of mysql

Comment: it did not work. I've tried a different way but it shows me 1970-01-01

(user3284... method)